# How can I get a role from IdentityServer4 authorization?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, identityserver4

I am using EF6 with IdentityServer4. Everything is the database - Users, Claims, and Clients.

How do I get User's Roles out of my bearer token to the clients? Currently I have a user with a Role named `CustomerAdministrator` assigned to my test but I am not able to get this role out.

My `CustomerAdministrator` role was added in tables:

- AspNetRoleClaims
- AspNetRoles
- AspNetUserRoles

What am i missing? 
Token result:

```
{
  "sid": "20d62652c0504f2b521c8a7c24ee7320",
  "sub": "a997a3ad-82bd-430f-9191-5b95408967b1",
  "auth_time": 1553518560,
  "idp": "local",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "name": "Bob Smith",
  "given_name": "Bob",
  "family_name": "Smith",
  "preferred_username": "bob"
}
```

The other solutions that I have found on Stack Overflow seem to be based on memory solutions.

Note: this is all based on the `Combined_AspId_and_EFStorage` example for IdentityServer4.

In Database:

```
ApsNetRoleClaims
1 | -uudi- | role | CustomerAdministrator

ApsNetRoles
1 | -uudi- | CustomerAdministrator | CustomerAdministrator | -uuid

ApsNetUserRoles
1 | -uuid User- | -uuid RoleId- 

ClientScopes
3 | api1 | 1
4 | openid | 4
5 | profile | 4
6 | api | 4
7 | profile | 3
8 | api | 3
10 | role | 1
11 | role | 2
12 | role | 3
13 | role | 4

IdentityResources
1 | 1 | openip | Your user identifier | NULL | 1 | 0 | 1 | ...
2 | 1 | profile| You profile...       | ...  | 0 | 1 | 1 | ...
3 | 6 | role   | User Role            | Role | 1 | 1 | 1 | ...
```

Comment: Did you include the `role` claim type to your identity resource or protected resource?

Comment: Opdated with what i added in database and what was in those tables what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, you want the login user's role from JWT-Token at client site?
If yes, you can pass the role name or role id at Claim objects.

```
            List<string> roleNames = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result.ToList();
            string userRoles = "";
            foreach(string rname in roleNames)
            {
                if (userRoles.Trim().Length == 0)
                    userRoles = rname;
                else
                    userRoles = userRoles + "," + rname;
            }
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("UserId", user.Id),
                new Claim("UserName", user.UserName),
                new Claim("UserRoles", userRoles),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,roleNames.FirstOrDefault()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.Id)
            };
```

From client site by angular

```
OnSubmit(userName,password){
  const jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();
  this.accountService.userAuthentication(userName,password).subscribe((data : any)=>{
  var decodedToken=jwtHelper.decodeToken(data.toString());
  var userRoles = decodedToken.UserRoles;
});
```